# Google app engine cron job on custom domain

Tags: php, google-app-engine, cron

Is there any way to run a cron job on a custom domain? I tried this in cron.yaml.

```
- description: Update old jobs
  url: http://example.com/cron/updateOldJobs
  schedule: every 1 hours
```

But it only gives me a syntax error when trying to upload.

I need this since we are running multiple domains on the same app engine. And then we are sending emails using a cron job to customers it is nice if it uses the correct domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the custom domain part of App engine? The target can only be pointed to the domain that the cron is on:

["The target string is prepended to your app's hostname. "](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_About_cron_yaml)

As a work around create a simple function that gets called by the cron job then do a URLFetch to poke your page.

Comment: If this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution There is no obligation to do this.